# Unsable to import from tensorflow after install. Please help understand and remove the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 63   try:
> ---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> 65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 from tensorflow import keras
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py in 
> 39 import sys as _sys
> 40
> ---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
> 42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
> 43
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py in
>
> 38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
> 39
> ---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
> 41 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
> 42
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in
>
> 33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
> 34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
> ---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
> 36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
> 37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in
>
> 26
> 27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
> ---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
> 29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
> in 
> 81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
> 82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
> ---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
> 84
> 85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 64, in 
> from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Similar issue in GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25597

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in jupyter notebook to install the tensorflow.

conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5

activate tensorflow

!pip install tensorflow.